# VNC view only mode on webpage

Tags: javascript, vnc

I have a PC with a VNC server running, and I need to display the screen of that PC on a webpage; however, the VNC server is configured in "view only" mode. So is it possible to show that screen on a webpage in a ?

I am trying to display a screen on a website through  VNC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VNC SDK to create an HTML 5-enabled Viewer app that will run in any desktop web browser*. This means there’s nothing for your users to download or install; simply embed the Viewer app in a web page, publish the URL, and your users will be able to connect to and control Windows, Mac, Linux or Raspberry Pi computers from web browsers wherever they happen to be!

For detailed explanation:
https://www.realvnc.com/en/news/control-computer-within-your-web-browser/